# Bluetooth configuration problem Hc-05 with Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno, baud-rate

I'm trying to set up my Bluetooth HC-05 but I'm having problems. I am using an Arduino Uno and I connect the bluetooth TX and RX cables to 0 and 1 of the Arduino. The code I am using is the following:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BT(0,1);
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 BT.begin(38400);  
 Serial.println("Introduzca un comando:"); 
}
void loop()
{
 if(BT.available()) 
 {
   Serial.write(BT.read());
 }
 if(Serial.available())
 {
    BT.write(Serial.read());
 }
}
```

The problem comes when I open the serial monitor to send AT commands but I do not receive the correct message, I receive the following image.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1StjO7i8S_lsV39meM8L2SeVMe-TT-ZPb/view?usp=sharing

I first show a message but when I enter the AT command, instead of receiving OK I receive xxxo. I suppose it is due to the bauds but I do not know how to put them, because the bluetooth I use was left to me and apparently it is already configured and I want to make changes, but it does not show me AT messages in a visible way.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following:

1. Configure the SoftwareSerial on 2 other pins rather than 0 and 1, because these are the UART pins of the Arduino Uno, maybe try SoftwareSerial(5,6)
2. Change the baud rate of the arduino Serial to 38400 in order to match the BT baud rate

Comment: Ok, I have already solved it, it was also because I had to put the KEY bluetooth pin to high (1), it would be as follows:
`void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(38400);   // Inicializamos  el puerto serie
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT); digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  Serial.println("Introduzca un comando:");
  BT.begin(38400);       // Inicializamos el puerto serie BT (Para Modo AT 2)
}`